# Email and Web split on different servers: Send email via PHP to an email on that domain

Tags: php, html-email

1 Domain that has port80 and MX split on the DNS:

- Website is hosted on a VPS.
- Email is hosted on a shared host.

When I call the mail() function in PHP on the website **that is addressed to an email on the domain**, the email is delivered LOCALLY to the VPS and not to the shared server.

In PHP running on the web host VPS using the domain MyDomain.com:

```
$headers = "From: MyName <name1@MyDomain.com>\r\n";
$headers .="Return-Path:<name1@MyDomain.com>\r\n";
mail( "name2@MyDomain.com", "Header", "Content", $headers);
```

How do I force mail() to do a MX lookup for the domain? How do I get the email delivered to the shared host and not the VPS?

I tried to do this but it didn't work:

```
ini_set("SMTP","123.456.789.012");
```

Where 123.456.789.012 is the ip to the shared host.

Shared host is hostmonster. Is there a way to specify the email box using the ip and username? name2~username@123.456.789.012

Comment: if smtp server is on a machine other than the one sending the mail it has to be set up to allow this, by default most are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the mail() function in favor of [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/). It is way more flexible, is object oriented, much easier to configure with SMTP and has much better attachments support (if you need it).

To send your email in phpmailer you'll just need something like this to set your SMTP:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mailer->Host = '123.456.789.012';
$mailer->From = 'me@myself.com';
$mailer->FromName = 'Me Myself';
$mailer->AddAddress = 'someRecipient@whatever.com';
$mailer->Subject = 'My subject line';
$mailer->Body = 'Your Body text here, in HTML if you set $mailer->IsHtml(true)';
$mailer->Send();
```

Comment: This is a good and long-term workaround for this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your VPS server is configured to handle mail for your domain.  Adjust your mail configuration accordingly.  Also, Linux ignores the SMTP setting.  Only Windows uses this.

Alternatively, you can use a class like PHPMailer which can connect to a remote SMTP server directly.

Comment: This was my first thought as well but email is shut down on this domain on the VPS.

Comment: @Travis, That doesn't mean the configuration is still wrong.  Your server thinks it is the mail server for your domain.  Otherwise, mail would be relayed.

Comment: Brad, I've gone so far as shutting down every daemon having anything to do with email in any way. I can't keep it like that for long as there are other domains there who do use those services. No luck though and I'm at a total loss.

Comment: @Travis, this doesn't have anything to do with the daemon, but configuration.  Post over on serverfault.com for help with the specific configuration issue.

Comment: Brad, I'll do this and you're likely completely correct. The VPS is running cPanel/WHM and when i shut down these services, WHM also handles all the config details. The comment from David was a valid workaround for my ignorance.